# Efficient method using only bit-wise operations

Tags: performance, algorithm, bit-manipulation

We are given `n` binary numbers, each of `k` bits. We need to find a `k` bit binary number in which `i`th bit is set only if the `i`th bit was set in exactly one of the `n` given binary numbers. For example,

```
0010
0011
0100
1110
```

should give `1001` as answer.You need to only use bit-wise operations to achieve this. Here is my solution:

```
unsigned int array[n];//we have our 'n' numbers here
unsigned int answer=0,rxor=0,t1,t2;
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
     t1 = answer;
     answer ^= array[i];
     t2 = (~t1) & answer;
     answer &= ~(t2 & rxor);
     rxor |= array[i];
}
```

The final answer will be stored in the `answer` variable. It uses a total of `7` bit-wise operations( 1 `xor`, 1 `or`, 2 `negation`, 3 `and` ) per iteration, making a total of `7*n` operations. My question is, can the number of operations can be reduced further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To derive the final answer, you need to know which bits have been used at least once, and which have been used at least twice. These two conditions can be computed very quickly:

```
unsigned usedOnce = 0;
unsigned usedTwice = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    usedTwice |= usedOnce & array[i];
    usedOnce |= array[i];
}
unsigned answer = usedOnce & ~usedTwice;
```

That's only three operations in the loop.